# cannot send email with flask-mail

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, flask-mail

I am trying to send Email with Flask-Mail,

This is the link of tutorial: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/send-email-programmatically-with-gmail-python-and-flask.html

**EMAIL_USER** and **EMAIL_PASSWORD** are environment variables, so I try to modify ~/.bashrc file(sudo vim ~/.bashrc) and add relevant information into them (in PyCharm Terminal), but it doesn't work, that is, it cannot echo something.

How to solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Here is the email sending code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

mail_settings = {
    "MAIL_SERVER": 'smtp.gmail.com',
    "MAIL_PORT": 465,
    "MAIL_USE_TLS": False,
    "MAIL_USE_SSL": True,
    "MAIL_USERNAME": os.environ['EMAIL_USER'],
    "MAIL_PASSWORD": os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
}

app.config.update(mail_settings)
mail = Mail(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        msg = Message(subject="Hello",
                      sender=app.config.get("MAIL_USERNAME"),
                      recipients=["<example@gmail.com>"], # replace with your email for testing
                      body="This is a test email I sent with Gmail and Python!")
        mail.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the variable to the .bashrc file you may need to restart your terminal to see it `echo` out. Try closing a reopening your pycharm terminal or pycharm itself.